# Table column error

Tags: tables

I want to include a description column for each variable but I got this error

[image]

Here my code :

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
  \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{natbib}
  \usepackage{eucal}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
   \usepackage{cuted}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{array}
     \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}      
      \usepackage{tabulary}
       \usepackage{tabularx}
       \usepackage{varioref}
       \usepackage{multirow}
         \usepackage{ragged2e}
        \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
        \usepackage{siunitx}                                        
        \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
         \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
         \usepackage{rotating}
        \usepackage{siunitx}
        \usepackage{makecell, threeparttable}
        \usepackage{xparse,xstring} % ditto     
         \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\scriptsize #1}}
          \newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\scriptsize}p{4.5cm}}
          \newcolumntype{R}{*{5}{>{\scriptsize}c}}
          \usepackage{dcolumn}
          \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}} 
           \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
    \begin{document}

   \begin{table}[h!]
     \caption{Descriptive Statistics for Banks’ financial data and macro variables}
      \label{tab1}
       \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}P@{\kern-30pt}R@{}}
         \toprule 
         \texttt{Variables} 
         & \mc{Description}              
         & \mc{No of observations}              
         &\mc{Mean}
         &\mc{Standard Deviation}
         &\mc{Maximum}
         &\mc{Minimum}\\[-2pt]
        \cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr) 
        {6-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-7}
 Specialization  & total loans-to-total assets ratio   & 8743 & 0.164 & 7.144 & 0659    & 0.046\\ 
 Credit quality  & Loans loss provision-to-total loans &8950  & 0.152 &5.102  &0.338    & 1.766  \\ 
 Diversification & Non-interest income-to-total income &8945  &0.245&10.172   &0.509    &0.396\\
 Profitability    &Return on assets (ROA)              &8746  &0.146&4.514    &0.132    &0.115\\
 Real GDP growth  & Quarter-over-Quarter growth        &8456  &0.045&0.612    &1.192    &0.010\\
 Log (Inflation)  &Quarter-over-Quarter growth         &8752  &0.123&3.890    &0.134    &0.118\\
 Log (unemployment rate) &Quarter-over-Quarter growth  &8563  &0.315&13.072   &0.508    &0.396\\
 Exchange rate  &Quarter-over-Quarter growth           &8745  &0.278&11.156   &0.543    &0.016\\
 \bottomrule 
   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You do not show your error but it is `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.` which is unrelated to tables, you have simply loaded `geometry` twice, with different options.

Comment: Then `! LaTeX Error: Command \mc already defined.` because you define `\mc` twice in the same preamble. It is best to _remove_ the whole preamble and only add packages or definitions if you need them.  You also have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` which is not needed unless you have an old latex, and `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} ` which is inconsistent with the utf8 setting

Comment: @David carslie .. thanks does it solve the problem of Minimum column?

Comment: It is inadvisable to go past more than one error, i scrolled past three then stopped. It would not be advisable to process any further into the document after so many errors in the preamble, so I assumed they were the errors you were asking about. You did not say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments and observations:

- You load the `geometry` package twice.
- You load `inputenc` twice, with incompatible options
- You define `\mc` twice. For the second (re)definition, you must use `\renewcommand`, not `\newcommand`.
- You define the `tabular` environment to have 6 columns overall, but the data show you actually have 7 columns.
- You define some custom column types but don't seem to be using all that much.

Anyway, as long as you're willing to abbreviate some of the header cells stings, you can make do with the basic `l` and `c` column types.

[image]

```
  \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
  %% (reduced the preamble to its bare minimum)
  \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{lmodern,eucal}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
  \usepackage{siunitx}  

  \begin{document}

  \begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{Descriptive statistics for banks' financial
           data and macro variables\strut}
  \label{tab1}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTex determine inter-col. whitespace
  \small
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
     ll cc S[table-format=2.3] cc @{}}
  \toprule 
  Variables & Description & No of obs & Mean
  & {Std Dev} & Max & Min \\
  \midrule
 Specialization  & total loans-to-total assets ratio  & 8743 & 0.164 & 7.144 & 0659    & 0.046\\ 
 Credit quality  & Loans loss provision-to-total loans&8950  & 0.152 & 5.102 &0.338    & 1.766\\ 
 Diversification & Non-interest income-to-total income&8945  & 0.245 &10.172 &0.509    & 0.396\\
 Profitability   &Return on assets (ROA)              &8746  & 0.146 & 4.514 &0.132    & 0.115\\ 
 \addlinespace
 Real GDP growth & q-o-q growth        &8456  & 0.045 & 0.612 &1.192    & 0.010\\
 Log (Inflation) &q-o-q growth         &8752  & 0.123 & 3.890 &0.134    & 0.118\\
 Log (unempl.\ rate) &q-o-q growth     &8563  & 0.315 &13.072 &0.508    & 0.396\\
 Exchange rate   &q-o-q growth         &8745  & 0.278 &11.156 &0.543    & 0.016\\
  \bottomrule 
  \end{tabular*}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: You saved me thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

After clean up your document preamble (see comments below your question) and remove all packages and new commands definitions, which are not needed in your table, I obtain the following result:

[image]

As you can see, some long column headers I wrote in two lines and use abbreviation for names. By this the column becomes narrowed and can fit in `\textwidth` using `\footnotesize` font sioze:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,  tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Descriptive Statistics for Banks’ financial data and macro variables}
\label{tab1}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l X cc S[table-format=2.3] cc @{}}
    \toprule
\texttt{Variables}
    & \makecell[b]{Description}
    & \makecell[b]{No of\\ observ.}
    & \makecell[b]{Mean}
    & {\makecell[b]{Standard\\ Deviation}}
    & \makecell[b]{Max}
    & \makecell[b]{Min}   \\
    \midrule
%\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr)
%{6-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-7}
Specialization  & total loans-to-total assets ratio   & 8743  & 0.164 &  7.144 & 0.659 & 0.046  \\
Credit quality  & Loans loss provision-to-total loans & 8950  & 0.152 &  5.102 & 0.338 & 1.766  \\
Diversification & Non-interest income-to-total income & 8945  & 0.245 & 10.172 & 0.509 & 0.396  \\
Profitability   & Return on assets (ROA)              & 8746  & 0.146 &  4.514 & 0.132 & 0.115  \\
Real GDP growth & Quarter-over-Quarter growth         & 8456  & 0.045 &  0.612 & 1.192 & 0.010  \\
Log (Inflation) & Quarter-over-Quarter growth         & 8752  & 0.123 &  3.890 & 0.134 & 0.118  \\
Log (unemployment rate) 
                & Quarter-over-Quarter growth         & 8563  & 0.315 & 13.072 & 0.508 & 0.396  \\
Exchange rate   & Quarter-over-Quarter growth         & 8745  & 0.278 & 11.156 & 0.543 & 0.016  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments :)